# Stuck in a concurrency proof

Tags: geometry

> Three squares are drawn on the sides of $\Delta ABC$ (i.e. the
> square on AB has AB as one of its sides and lies outside
> $\Delta ABC$). Show that the lines drawn from the vertices A, B, C
> to the centers of the opposite squares are concurrent.

I found a solution [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ecargue/arml/archive/13-14/geometry-12-15-13.pdf) but was not able to understand how the areas of $\Delta ABA'$ and $\Delta CBC'$ are equal. This is crucial for Ceva to work so please help in proving that the areas of mentioned triangles are equal.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $CB=\sqrt{2} A'B$ and $AB=\sqrt{2}C'B$

So we can compare the areas of triangles as
$$[\triangle ABA']=\frac{1}{2}A'B\cdot AB \cdot \sin ABA'$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{CB\cdot AB}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \sin(B+45^\circ)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}CB\cdot C'B \cdot \sin CBC'=[\triangle CBC']$$

Comment: Thanks I can complete the rest of the proof now.